# Apache Reverse Proxy Config

Tags: apache, reverse-proxy, redhat

I am looking for some advice on how can I fix my existing reverse proxy config.
The URL that i am using is the config is a GTM + LTM LB, on which if the US servers are down, the UK servers will be serving the requests

```
#Reverse Proxy Settings 
ProxyRequests Off 
ProxyPreserveHost On

SSLProxyEngine on 
SSLProxyCACertificateFile XXXX.cer

SSLProxyCheckPeerCN off 
SSLProxyVerify none 
SSLProxyCheckPeerName off
SSLProxyCheckPeerExpire off

<Location /XXXXX>
ProxyPass https://LB_URL retry=0
ProxyPassReverse https://LB_URL
</Location>
```

Now, the issue is that when the LB_URL switches to UK servers, the reverse proxy does not seem to re-route the requests and is stuck with the GTM US IP address instead switching to the GMT UK IP Addresses

I used to have retry=60 as default, changes to retry=0, but will only work if i restart httpd or the GTM LB US IP becomes available.

I was thinking to put a balancer set, with the same URL twice, like below

```
.....
<Proxy balancer://myset>
     BalancerMember https://LB_URL
     BalancerMember http://LB_URL status=+R
     ProxySet lbmethod=byrequests 
</Proxy>
 
<Location /location>
ProxyPass balancer://myset/ 
ProxyPassReverse balancer://myset/ 
</Location>
```